# NodeSq does not conform to expected type integer

Tags: java, xml, scala

I cannot resolve `scala xml` value to integer. How to fix it?

**Error:**

```
NodeSq does not conform to expected type integer
```

**Code:**

```
import scala.io._
import scala.xml._

object Weather {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    getWeatherData()
  }
  def getWeatherData()={
    val url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlin&mode=xml"
    val responce = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
    val xmlResponce = XML.loadString(responce)
    val kelvin: Integer = xmlResponce \\ "temperature" \\ "@value"
    println( kelvin-273.15)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(xmlResponce \\ "temperature" \\ "@value").text.toInt`